# Android Studio Cannot past

Tags: android-studio, copy, paste

Content is too large(128.54MB), limit is 20.97

i am building large app, that can reach up to 2Million lines of code.
i need to copy and paste some functions. and i got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to Help>Edit Custom Properties

there enter

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=10240 //adjust according to your need, in KB
```

[image: Help menu list]

[image: What to write inside]